# Getting physical address from /proc/[pid]/pagemap fails

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management

I am trying to get physical address from /proc/[pid]/pagemap using virtual address and I thought it was working fine until I tried with a simple test program.
This is my code which gets physical address using virtual address:

```
#include "addresstranslation.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define PAGEMAP_ENTRY 8
#define GET_BIT(X,Y) (X & ((uint64_t)1<<Y)) >> Y
#define GET_PFN(X) X & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFF
#define page_mapping_file "/proc/self/pagemap"

const int __endian_bit = 1;
#define is_bigendian() ( (*(char*)&__endian_bit) == 0 )


uintptr_t virtual_to_physical_address(uintptr_t virt_addr)
{
   uintptr_t file_offset = 0;
   uintptr_t read_val = 0;
   uintptr_t page_number = 0;
   int i = 0;
   int c = 0;
   int pid = 0;
   int status = 0;
   unsigned char c_buf[PAGEMAP_ENTRY];

   FILE *f = fopen(page_mapping_file, "rb");
   if(!f)
   {
      // if this happens run as root
      printf("Error! Cannot open %s. Please, run as root.\n", page_mapping_file);
      return 0;
   }

   file_offset = virt_addr / getpagesize() * PAGEMAP_ENTRY;

   status = fseek(f, file_offset, SEEK_SET);
   if(status)
   {
      printf("Error! Cannot seek in %s.\n", page_mapping_file);
      perror("Failed to do fseek!");
      fclose(f);
      return 0;
   }

   for(i = 0; i < PAGEMAP_ENTRY; i++)
   {
      c = getc(f);
      if(c == EOF)
      {
         fclose(f);
         return 0;
      }

      if(is_bigendian())
      {
           c_buf[i] = c;
      }
      else
      {
           c_buf[PAGEMAP_ENTRY - i - 1] = c;
      }
   }

   for(i=0; i < PAGEMAP_ENTRY; i++)
   {
      read_val = (read_val << 8) + c_buf[i];
   }

   /*
   if(GET_BIT(read_val, 63))
   {
      page_number = GET_PFN(read_val);
      printf("%d \n", page_number);
   }
   else
   {
     printf("Page not present\n");
   }
   if(GET_BIT(read_val, 62))
   {
      printf("Page swapped\n");
   }
   */
   fclose(f);

   return read_val;
}
```

addresstranslation.h:

```
/*
 * addresstranslation.h
 *
 *  Translates virtual to physical address.
 */

#ifndef __ADDRESS_TRANSLATION_H
#define __ADDRESS_TRANSLATION_H

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uintptr_t virtual_to_physical_address(uintptr_t virt_addr);

#endif
```

And this is the simple test that I tried.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "addresstranslation.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int *a1, *a2, *b1,*c1, *b2 = NULL;
   int N = 4096;
   uintptr_t ap1, ap2, bp1, bp2 = 0;

   printf("Test virtual to physical address translation.\n");

   a1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
   if (!a1)
   {
      printf("Error: cannot allocate memory for a\n");
      return 1;
   }

   b1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
   if (!b1)
   {
      printf("Error: cannot allocate memory for b\n");
      return 1;
   }

   ap1 = virtual_to_physical_address((uintptr_t)a1);
   bp1 = virtual_to_physical_address((uintptr_t)b1);

   printf("a1_virt= %p: a1_phys= %" PRIxPTR "\n", a1, ap1);
   printf("b1_virt= %p b1_phys= %" PRIxPTR "\n", b1, bp1);
   a2 = a1 + 1000;
   b2 = b1 + 1;
   ap2 = virtual_to_physical_address((uintptr_t)a2);
   bp2 = virtual_to_physical_address((uintptr_t)b2);
   printf("a2_virt= %p a2_phys= %" PRIxPTR "\n", a2, ap2);
   printf("b2_virt= %p b2_phys= %" PRIxPTR "\n", b2, bp2);
   printf("Done\n");
}
```

Which prints something like this:

```
Test virtual to physical address translation.

a1_virt= 0x958d008: a1_phys= 4f8ce
b1_virt= 0x9591010 b1_phys= 4d40b
a2_virt= 0x958dfa8 a2_phys= 4f8ce
b2_virt= 0x9591014 b2_phys= 4d40b
Done
```

As you can see a1 and a2 have different virtual addresses but have same physical address, my question is; Is my virtual-physical address conversion faulty or is it about Linux memory management and it is possible one physical address can be mapped to two different virtual addresses ?

Comment: the posted code does not even begin to compile.  Strongly suggest enabling all warnings when compiling, then fix those warnings and errors.  (for gcc, use, at a minimum: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: I fixed the syntax errors happened when I copied wrong way and added addresstranslation.h for compiling. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a device which allow multiple `open` and `mmap` you could get multiple virtual for one physical

Comment: where have you got that two processes cannot share the same physical memory page (for example two instances of `ls(1)` program text segment) for a text shared segment???

Answer (score 1):

the C language is case sensitive.

so this macro:

```
#DEFINE PAGE_MAPPING_FILE "/PROC/self/pagemap"
```

is not invoked when using:

```
FILE *f = fopen(page_mapping_file, "rb");
```

and `#DEFINE` means nothing to the C compiler.

The correct spelling is: `#define`  I.E. all lower case

Comment: Thanks, it is lower case in my code but when I copied it changed I assume. I will edit the question but my real question is still unanswered.

Comment: @Tugberk, you had better to be precise in your questions, so we don't lose time thinking you had make mistakes in your code.  And you had better to be more precise even in your own coding.  For a precise definition on how to interpret that proc file, the most precise source you have is in your own machine (the kernel source code). I cannot fully understand why do you need the precise mapping from virtual to physical memory, as everything in your box need to use some kind of virtual addressing (even the kernel constructs a mapping to see your code).  Read the source of `copy_{to,from}_user()`